# JQuery Scrolling/Paging Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, scroll

I am trying to create a simple tab bar for a site that has the ability to scroll for tabs that do not fit on the page. This is quite simple and does not need to have any ajax or dynamically loaded content...it simply displays all the tabs, and when you click one, it takes you to another page.

I have scoured the internet and can not seem to find anything other than:
http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tabs/tabs-adv.html
however this is very heavy and complicated...I am looking for a lightweight example in jquery. If anyone can help I would be grateful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up writing it myself with a div who's overflow is set to hidden. Then used the jquery below to move the tabs in the div.

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('.scrollButtons .left').click(function()
      {
        var content = $(".tabs .scrollable .content")
        var pos = content.position().left + 250;
        if (pos >= 0)
        {
            pos = 0;
        }
        content.animate({ left: pos }, 1000);
      });
      $('.scrollButtons .right').click(function()
      {
        var content = $(".tabs .scrollable .content")
        var width = content.children('ul').width();
        var pos = content.position().left - 250;
        //var width = content.width();
        if (pos <= (width * -1) + 670)
        {
            pos = (width * -1) + 600;
        }
        content.animate({ left: pos }, 1000);
      });
    });
```

My Html looked like this:

```
    <div class="tabs">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Tab1</li>
                <li>Tab2</li>
                <li>Tab3</li>
                <li>Tab4</li>
                <li>Tab5</li>                    
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollButtons">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="left">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="right">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chris do you remember css for it ?

Comment: I was just able to use this code and it worked great.  I did have to replace left with marginLeft in the script though.  @Goran I used a tags for my left and right and floated them left and right and floated .content left.  set a width and overflow:hidden on .content finally changed 2 script lines var pos = +content.css("marginLeft").replace("px", "") - 600; and content.animate({ marginLeft: pos }, 1000);

Answer (score 6):

I have just created a plugin myself:
Project home: http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jst

Comment: Hey, are you keeping up on this? It seems that it doesn't work with newer versions of JQuery and JQuery UI. For the most part that is.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply wrap the tabs in a DIV with overflow-x: auto set in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I always use [JQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) as a starting point for tabs. You can customize the JQuery UI download in the download section of the website. This method should be lighter than any other implementation, if you are already using JQuery on your website.

Out of the box, the JQuery UI tabs will not give you the scrolling you desire. This I believe could be achieved by altering the CSS, but more than likely will be easier if you alter the navigation of your site (i.e. create more levels, use shorter titles).

Hope this helps